# React Native Typescript testing with Jest

Tags: typescript, react-native, ts-jest

I faced a problem with writing the jest test for a react-native app. The app uses typescript. I am new to typescript and cannot figure out how to pass navigation props to component.  I have followed examples and tutorials but had no success.
Error message, component code and test code are as follows:

Error message:

```
__tests__/Signin.test.tsx:30:42 - error TS2322: Type '{ state: { params: {}; }; dispatch: jest.Mock<any, any>; goBack: jest.Mock<any, any>; dismiss: jest.Mock<any, any>; navigate: () => void; openDrawer: jest.Mock<any, any>; ... 15 more ...; setOptions: (options: '') => any; }' is not assignable to type 'MainNavigationProp<MainRoutes.Signin>'.
  Type '{ state: { params: {}; }; dispatch: jest.Mock<any, any>; goBack: jest.Mock<any, any>; dismiss: jest.Mock<any, any>; navigate: () => void; openDrawer: jest.Mock<any, any>; ... 15 more ...; setOptions: (options: '') => any; }' is not assignable to type '{ setParams(params: undefined): void; setOptions(options: Partial<StackNavigationOptions>): void; }'.
    Types of property 'setOptions' are incompatible.
      Type '(options: '') => any' is not assignable to type '(options: Partial<StackNavigationOptions>) => void'.
        Types of parameters 'options' and 'options' are incompatible.
          Type 'Partial<StackNavigationOptions>' is not assignable to type '""'.

30     const tree = renderer.create(<Signin navigation={store} />).toJSON()
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~

  app/ui/screens/Signin.tsx:14:5
    14     navigation: MainNavigationProp<MainRoutes.Signin>
           ~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'navigation' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SigninProps'
__tests__/Signin.test.tsx:29:5 - error TS1005: '=>' expected.

29     }
       ~
```

My component:

```js
import { MainNavigationProp } from "../../navigation/types"
import { MainRoutes } from "../../navigation/routes"


type SigninProps = {
    navigation: MainNavigationProp<MainRoutes.Signin>
}
export default function Signin({ navigation }: SigninProps) {

    return (
        <View>
  
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate(MainRoutes.ForgotPassword)
                }}>
                <Text>GO TO "ForgotPassword"</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                 onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate(MainRoutes.Signup)
                }}>
                <Text>GO TO "Signup"</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Test code:

```js
import React from "react"
import renderer from "react-test-renderer"
import Signin from "../app/ui/screens/Signin"

test("render correctly", () => {
    const store = {
        state: { params: {} },
        dispatch: jest.fn(),
        goBack: jest.fn(),
        dismiss: jest.fn(),
        navigate: ()=>{},
        openDrawer: jest.fn(),
        closeDrawer: jest.fn(),  
        toggleDrawer: jest.fn(),
        getParam: jest.fn(),
        setParams: jest.fn(),
        addListener: jest.fn(),
        push: jest.fn(),
        replace: jest.fn(),
        pop: jest.fn(),
        popToTop: jest.fn(),
        isFocused: jest.fn(),
        reset: jest.fn(),
        canGoBack: jest.fn(),
        getParent: jest.fn(),
        getState: jest.fn(),
        removeListener: jest.fn(),   
        setOptions:(options: '')     
    }
    const tree = renderer.create(<Signin navigation={store} />).toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchInlineSnapshot()
})
```

IDE warning when hover over props:

```js
(property) navigation: MainNavigationProp<MainRoutes.Signin>
Type '{ state: { params: {}; }; dispatch: jest.Mock<any, any>; goBack: jest.Mock<any, any>; dismiss: jest.Mock<any, any>; navigate: () => void; openDrawer: jest.Mock<any, any>; ... 15 more ...; setOptions: (options: '') => any; }' is not assignable to type 'MainNavigationProp<MainRoutes.Signin>'.
  Type '{ state: { params: {}; }; dispatch: jest.Mock<any, any>; goBack: jest.Mock<any, any>; dismiss: jest.Mock<any, any>; navigate: () => void; openDrawer: jest.Mock<any, any>; ... 15 more ...; setOptions: (options: '') => any; }' is not assignable to type '{ setParams(params: undefined): void; setOptions(options: Partial<StackNavigationOptions>): void; }'.
    Types of property 'setOptions' are incompatible.
      Type '(options: '') => any' is not assignable to type '(options: Partial<StackNavigationOptions>) => void'.
        Types of parameters 'options' and 'options' are incompatible.
          Type 'Partial<StackNavigationOptions>' is not assignable to type '""'.ts(2322)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there a warning in your IDE when you hover your props ? if yes could you update your question with it

Comment: @DarioRega there is a warning. i had updated question